How to implement a "scanner" effect on Linux to fix documents with varying darkness of background?
I use Linux, and sometimes I need to make a document printable when it was photographed in a very imperfect way. A page from a rather complicated example that I recently needed to handle is this one:

Usually, playing with levels or curves produces workable output. But not in this one, because different parts have very different light/darkness. So either I lose some of the line image (score) on the top left, or else the bottom right has some darkness on the background, which makes the score hard to read when printed on a laser printer.
This particular image was successfully fixed by onlinecamscanner.com - but (a) there is no fine-tuning there so it does not work on everything, (b) it's rather awkward to use, especially its crop stage, (c) what if this service goes away?
So, I'd like some way to have an effect like that on my Linux machine. An effect that preserves the image (which is all dark lines) but makes the background white. Ideally more tunable than what is on that website. Where can I get this?

This likely can be solved with a high pass filter. There are high pass filter plugins available for GIMP IIRC

The mkbitmap command of potrace (part of the potrace package in Debian and Ubuntu) can give very nice results in these cases with very little effort. I suggest taking a look at https://potrace.sourceforge.net/mkbitmap.html

Adding as a comment since it's not the question you asked... I've had good luck photographing documents using Google's PhotoScan app on my phone.

I use ImageMagick for this. It occurs often enough for me1 that I wrote a simple script called flatten_image:
#!/bin/bash

# Use ImageMagick to improve badly lit, low contrast photos of line drawings
# and text.
#
# Usage: flatten_image <input image> <output image>

convert $1 \( +clone -blur 30x30 -negate \) -compose Plus -composite -normalize $2

It basically performs a high-pass filter by subtracting a low-pass filtered version of the image from the original, and then contrast-stretching the result.
Without any tweaking, it does the following to your image. It works best if you crop away any high-contrast edges on the image.


1 I should say "occurred". I used to be a moderator on EE.SE, and people kept uploading badly-lit pictures of their hand-drawn diagrams, and I created this script to quickly fix them.

Median filter is also a good fit since it "ignores" the thin black lines and just extracts the background. Not sure if ImageMagick supports it though.

It does, you just replace -blur 30x30 with -statistic median 30x30

In such cases, with gimp and a little bit of manual labor:

select the brightest WHITE spot, and apply levels and set white point to that

after that, switch to quickmask, and make black-white gradient from that brightest white spot to the darkest white spot, and switch off quick mask
now, select the darkest WHITE spot, apply levels and set white point



If the gradient wasn't so smooth across the page you could probably combine this approach with Reinmar Bielau's by first using the dilate trick to get a "clean page", contrast-expanding it, and then using it as a mask for a second Levels operation.

“select the brightest WHITE spot” — while it’s not an issue in the OP’s picture, it might be good to note that this should be a pixel that’s not clipped in any channel, otherwise the balance is likely to turn out off.

My approach is to approximate a clean background first, then use it to get uniform brightness


Copy layer
Apply a small radius (~1) Gaussian Blur filter
Apply Dilate filter, big enough to hide all ink on the page
Use Subtract or Divide blending mode, I don't have GIMP on hand, so use whichever looks right to you
Now that image has a uniform brightness, merge layers and use levels or curves as usual

With some sane defaults you can automate this process in gimp or otherwise (ImageMagick, Python)

This is a very common task in computer vision: keyword thresholding.
If you would like to implement this yourself programmatically and are willing to get your hands dirty, OpenCV has functions for adaptive thresholding, which determines local thresholds for pixels instead of a single global value. Gaussian Thresholding uses a Gaussian kernel, meaning closest neighborhood values are weighted the most, with the weight of further values falling off exponentially. Another trick to reduce noise at the expense of sharpness is a tiny Gaussian blur, but you'll have to decide what amount of sharpness is needed.


I do a poor man's version of adaptive thresholding by using GIMP Threshold tool iteratively over rectangular selections until I cover the whole picture.

This is a common issue with scanned or photographed documents. The image can be readily improved with image editing tools.
In the example below, I used free IrfanView, a small Windows application that runs well under wine in Linux, but powerful, free GIMP which you've installed can perform that task, too. GIMP, being so powerful, is also complex and has a longer learning curve.

This quick edit used just a few features, and certainly can be improved. Though the directions include IrfanView shortcuts, the same tools can be found in GIMP.

Open the file in the image editor.
Open the dialog(s) to adjust the following, and edit as needed. [In IrfanView, press ShiftG.]

Contrast
Gamma
Brightness


Likely, the image will print better if it is made monochrome (i.e., grayscale), and if the number of colors (shades of gray) is reduced. [In IrfanView, press CtrlG to make grayscale, and menu item Image | Decrease color depth for that dialog.]

Other ways to improve the image involve use of tools to rotate and flatten the image, e.g., Perspective Transformations .8bf extension for Adobe and IrfanView.

GIMP has the worst UI of any image editing program I've ever used, and GNOME devs actively refuse to improve it. Krita is open source and does a much better job at UI, though being for a somewhat different purpose.

@qwr, GIMP is highly regarded by professionals -- but it also has an idiosyncratic interface that takes a while to learn. Considering it provides many of the pricey Adobe tools in a free, open-source app, there many users willing to learn it. (Or consider the software developer's motto, "It's not a bug; it's a feature.")

I am all for providing alternatives to Adobe's anti-consumer products, but I think GIMP's UI is actively hindering its acceptance. Compare it to other popular open source tools like Blender or MuseScore, which both have intuitive interfaces that match user expectations.

@DrMoishePippik GIMP was highly-regarded by professionals… a decade ago. Nowadays, I only ever hear praise for Krita. Having used Krita a few times (compared to continuous use over multiple years for GIMP), I find Krita easier for everything except cropping screenshots, which is muscle memory in GIMP.

@wizzwizz4 frankly I don't know any artist or professional who uses GIMP - it's a joke, compared to Photoshop, Krita, or even online tools.
